# Validating symfony2 form with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, entity

This is my first project with Symfony2 and I'm trying to persist an entity with an ajax. Here is some sample code:

**routing**

```
...
version_ajax_create:
path:     /ajax-create
defaults: { _controller: "CustomNameBundle:Version:ajax" }
methods:  POST
...
```

**controller**

```
public function ajaxAction()
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $em      = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity  = new Version();

        // Get data from ajax
        $project_id = $request->request->get('project_id', 'null');
        // Get project and pass it to the entity
        $project = $em->getRepository('CustomNameBundle:Project')->find(array(
            'id' => $project_id
        ));

        $entity->setProject($project);

        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $response = array('success' => true);
        } else {
            $response = array('success' => false);
        }

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
```

**view**

```
  $('#add_new_version').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ path('version_ajax_create') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'project_id': '{{ entity.id }}' }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert('success!')
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            alert('fail!')
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

The Version entity itself has id(autogenerated), create and modified date (with lifecicle callbacks) and an **associated project id(many to 1 relation).**

I'm trying to create a new version just passing the project id.

I think the problem came from this line

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

It expects a serialized $request not just a JSON obj.

If I disable the form validation and persist direct the entity it will be saved successfully, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice at all.

Any help or advice how to proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, If I understood you right, you should be able to use:

```
$project_id = $request->request->get('project_id', 'null');
$form->submit(['form_name' => ['project_id' => $project_id ]]);

if ( $form->isValid() ){

}
```

I am not sure about what you said:

> It expects a serialized $request not just a JSON obj.

I am aware that `AngularJS` uses `JSON` to transport data to server, however, I didn't know that `jQuery` does that as well. Does it?

Comment: Project id is a field in the form. I try your code but it also doesn't work... Actually I think that my concept for creating and submitting the form is not right (and maybe the validation fails because of those hidden inputs that symfony2 creates in the form).

I removed the form stuffs and the validation and added a try-catch statement for checking if the entity is persisted successfully. I'm sure that this is not a good practice and any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.